# Why is the definite article "the" used instead of "an" in the description of a parameter of a PHP function

Tags: articles

When I read the description of the parameters of the function **html_entity_decode** here https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php#refsect1-function.html-entity-decode-parameters, I can't understand why for the "string" parameter it reads:

```
The input string
```

instead of

```
An input string
```

Firstly, the first argument can be *any* string, not just a specific one. Secondly, the description of the second "flags" parameter begins with the indefinite article "a":

```
A bitmask of one or more of the following flags...
```

which is correct, because it can take more than one value.

I will really appreciate if you help me comprehend this, because there are no articles in my mother tongue.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that the mix of articles seems a little strange, but it also feels natural to me as a native English speaker and a technician.  Here is how I would explain it.

"The input string" is not just "any string", but the one *specific* input string that is being used for this function. This is hinted at in the description, where it says

> **html_entity_decode()** is the opposite of htmlentities() in that it converts HTML entities in the `string`...

So we're already talking about a specific string.

But the author hasn't mentioned `flags` before, so it's a first reference to it, and therefore simply "*a* bitmask".

Comment: It's similar to if you have a recipe for roast chicken, it might say "First, wash the chicken. Then place it in a roasting tray."

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that if the string was not mentioned before the parameter description, it would still be correct to say "The input string"?

Comment: @ko1Rn No, if the string were never mentioned before, it would sound more natural to say "This function takes **a** string as an argument."  I think the example from your question is hard to answer either way, though, because it's not really part of a full sentence, but a kind of "headlinese".

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation!